# How to format NewRelic NerdGraph API calls from java/groovy client?

Tags: graphql, newrelic, graphql-java

I'm trying to extract some metric data from NewRelic using NerdGraph API. It works perfectly while using curl, but I'm having problems with calling it from groovy/java client.
NerdGraph API request is as follows:

```
    {
      actor {
        entitySearch(query: "name like 'my-service-name'") {
          results {
            entities {
              tags {
                key
                values
              }
              guid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The following curl call works fine:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.newrelic.com/graphql' --header 'API-Key: MY-API-KEY' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"query":"{\n  actor {\n    entitySearch(query: \"name like '\''my-service-name'\''\") {\n      results {\n        entities {\n          tags {\n            key\n            values\n          }\n          guid\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}"}'
```

In my groovy code I'm trying to instantiate request like this:

```
    String request = '''
{ "query":  "{
  actor {
    entitySearch(query: "name like 'my-service-name'") {
      results {
        entities {
          tags {
            key
            values
          }
          guid
        }
      }
    }
  }
}"
 }
'''
```

..or this:

```
    String request = '{"query":"{\n  actor {\n    entitySearch(query: \"name like \'my-service-name\'\") {\n      results {\n        entities {\n          tags {\n            key\n            values\n          }\n          guid\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}"}'
```

Neither works. I'm getting https://api.newrelic.com/graphql -> 400 : Bad Request
How should I escape special characters (quote and double quote) to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in C# and came to this question looking for answers.  Hopefully you've found a solution, but for me the key was sending the data as a byte[] as opposed to a string...

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://api.newrelic.com/graphql"))
    {
        string payload = @"{actor {account(id: NEWRELICACCOUNTID) {nrql(query: ""SELECT rate(count(*), 1 hour) AS 'RequestsPerHour' FROM Transaction TIMESERIES 1 hour FACET `Channel` EXTRAPOLATE SINCE 1 weeks ago"") {results}}}}";
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("API-Key", "MYAPIKEY");
        request.Content = new ByteArrayContent(encoding.GetBytes(payload)); 
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
 }
```

Hope this helps you or someone else!